# PHP MYSQL Query Column does not return when using RTRIM() or UPPER()

Tags: php, mysql

Super simple query:

```
mysql_connect($server ,$username,$password);

@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

$query="SELECT RTRIM(a.Name), a.Age, a.Sex, a.GunTime, a.Pace, b.Name as Race,  
a.RaceDate from 5K as a Join RaceIDs b on a.RaceID = b.ID Order By GunTime asc";

$result=mysql_query($query);
```

When this query executes, all of the columns return except for a.Name.  If I remove the`RTRIM()` then the a.Name column returns as expected.  Likewise, if I pass `UPPER(a.Name)`, then that one column is empty.  If I remove the `UPPER()`, then `a.Name` returns just fine.

Any clue why I can't wrap these table-aliased arguments in standard MYSQL (v5.1) functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provide a column alias for the function-wrapped columns:

```
SELECT RTRIM(a.Name) AS Name ...
```

Now when you fetch results (either `mysql_fetch_assoc()` or `mysql_fetch_array()`) the `Name` column will exist in your result row.  `($row['Name'])`

Otherwise, the column is technically there, but you would have to reference it as `RTRIM(a.Name)` when fetching in PHP: `($row['RTRIM(a.Name)'])`

Comment: Excellent.  Tested and works perfectly.  Answer accepted.  Thanks for your help.